# I want to resolve the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Tags: python, api, pysimplegui

I'm using a Warframe API to do a program that sees what, when, and where the Void Trader is selling items with PySimpleGUI. I think that my code's syntax is correct but when I run the program, it says that there are too many values, probably because the API is too big. Can someone help me?

*This is my code:*

```
import requests
import PySimpleGUI as sg

r = requests.get('https://api.warframestat.us/pc')
void = r.json()['voidTrader']
start = void['startString']
end = void['endString']
location = void['location']

layout = [
[sg.Text('When will it start?', start)],
[sg.Text('When will it end?', end)],
[sg.Text('Where will it be?', location)]
]

window = sg.Window('Warframe Void Trader viewer', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
```

Comment: If you see the line, it will probably point to the line where `window.read()` is. Looks a whole lot like an issue trying to unpack too many values from a Tuple. Check the API for `window.read()` and confirm how many values it returns.

Comment: agreed. to illustrate, the following line produces the same type of error: `a,b = (1,2,3)`

Comment: How should i check the API for `window.read()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by wrong arguments you passed to `sg.Text`.

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Text('When will it start?', start)],
    [sg.Text('When will it end?', end)],
    [sg.Text('Where will it be?', location)]
]
```

For `sg.Text.__init__`,

```py
def __init__(self, text='', size=(None, None), auto_size_text=None, click_submits=False, enable_events=False, relief=None, font=None, text_color=None, background_color=None, border_width=None, justification=None, pad=None, key=None, k=None, right_click_menu=None, grab=None, tooltip=None, visible=True, metadata=None):
```

If you didn't use the keyword for each keyword arguments, then `text` will be 'When will it start?', `size` will be `start` in case

```py
sg.Text('When will it start?', start)
```

option `size` as a two-tuple `(width, height)`, but you just give it one string, so it got the exception,

```py
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

You can solve it by

```py
sg.Text(' '.join(['When will it start?', str(start)]))
```